# sql modifying output of a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a query that returns a table

```
key     value
a_1         5
c_4         9
a_2         3
b_1         4
b_3         1
```

Say I would want to modify my keys so that each b would b replaced with a d so that the table would look like

```
key     value
a_1         5
c_4         9
a_2         3
d_1         4  <--modified
d_3         1  <--modified
```

how could I do that in sql (oracle)?

Edit: the entries in this table are sums over values. When I follow the advice of the first two respondents, sql would not group over key anymore but give the error message "missing expression".
I tried defining the key REPLACE(key, 'b', 'd') as newKey and Group by newKey, but that did not work as well.
Any idea how I can solve this?

Edit 2: Grouping works as well in the proposed solutions. Had a mistake on my side. Thanks

Comment: You will have to give more details about your table and the query that gives this data. The logic to replace b with d is not clear.

Comment: as you are using keywords/reserved words for your fieldname, therefore you where not getting the result, try the ans i added, it works in Oracle with the same field name you gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
WITH t(KEY, VALUE) AS
(
     SELECT 'a_1', 5 FROM dual
     union
     SELECT 'c_4', 9 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 'a_2', 3 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 'b_1', 4 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 'b_3', 1 FROM dual
)
SELECT REPLACE(KEY, 'b', 'd') key1 , value
       FROM t
ORDER BY key1;
```

/

```
KEY1      VALUE
---- ----------
a_1           5
a_2           3
c_4           9
d_1           4
d_3           1
```

Comment: Thanks. i simplified the query a bit in the question. The actual query would sum over keys sum(key) and group by key. this does not work anymore after the replace. see edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT REPLACE(`key`, 'b', 'd') key, `value` FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query, **This query works in Oracle 11g R2**

```
SELECT REPLACE("key", 'b', 'd') as "key", "value" FROM Table1;;
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b17c/11

Please don't use field-names as key and value, they can clash at many places in any query